# Batch: Net share and Net use error

Tags: batch-file, net-use

I'm trying to connect to my other pc, with `net share` and `net use` commands, sadly, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Here are the codes:

SHARE:

```
sc config lanmanserver start= auto
net start lanmanserver
net user Test 1234 /add
net localgroup administrators /ADD Test (This doesn't work btw.)
net share C=C:\ /UNLIMITED
pause
```

USE:

```
net use Z: \\IPv4 Address\c$
pause
```

When running the code, it says:

```
System error 86 has occurred.
The Specified network password is not correct.
```

I typed `Test` as the Username and `1234` as the password. I also tried to add a user manually, and add administrator rights manually, still no success.

UPDATE: The command: `net localgroup administrators /ADD Test`, didn't work, because I used a Danish version of Windows. Figured it out. Still not sure why the system 86 error occurs, and my password is incorrect.

Comment: You defined the share name `C`, not `C$` (which is an administrative share that is defined automatically on some older versions of Windows).

Comment: Thank you, Klitos, I think I might have overseen that. Typical ;). Thank for your help, it's really appreciated.